# How to map a SchemaRDD to a PairRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to figure out how to map a SchemaRDD object that I retrieved from a sql HiveContext over to a PairRDDFunctions[String, Vector] object where the string value is the name column in the schemaRDD and the  rest of the columns (BytesIn, BytesOut, etc...) are the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have columns: "name", "bytesIn", "bytesOut"

```
val schemaRDD: SchemaRDD = ...
val pairs: RDD[(String, (Long, Long)] = 
  schemaRDD.select("name", "bytesIn", "bytesOut").rdd.map { 
     case Row(name, bytesIn, bytesOut) => 
       name -> (bytesIn, bytesOut)
  }

// To import PairRDDFunctions via implicits
import SparkContext._

pairs.groupByKey ... etc
```